# sim800l gsm module reboot command

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

i have a project to control a relay by sms and call by arduino and sim800L gsm modem 
and i need to modify the code below to by adding command to reboot or reset the modem ever hour 
i mean delete all sms and call history and reboot the modem because the modem is always on for long time and the modem after few days of operation becomes not responsive
any one can help me and solve the problem

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(10,11);  // (Rx,Tx  > Tx,Rx) 

char incomingByte; 
String inputString;
int relay = 4; // Output for Relay Control
int LEDG = 8;
int buzzer = 5;
int LED = 6;
int buttonPin = 2;
int buttonState = 0; 
void setup() 
{
      pinMode(relay, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(LED , OUTPUT);
        pinMode(LEDG , OUTPUT);
      pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
      digitalWrite(relay, LOW); // Initial state of the relay
       digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
        digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
        digitalWrite(LEDG, LOW);


      Serial.begin(9600);
      mySerial.begin(9600); 

     while(!mySerial.available()){
        mySerial.println("AT");
        delay(1000); 
        Serial.println("Connecting...");
        }
      Serial.println("Connected!"); 
      delay(30000); 



      mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");  //Set SMS to Text Mode 

      delay(1000); 

      mySerial.println("AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0");  //Procedure to handle newly arrived messages(command name in text: new message indications to TE) 
      delay(1000);
      mySerial.println("AT+CMGL=\"REC UNREAD\""); // Read Unread Messages
      delay(1000);
       mySerial.println("AT+CLIP=1");
        delay(1000);
      digitalWrite( LEDG , HIGH);
     }

void loop()
{ 


 m:
  if(mySerial.available()> 0){
      delay(100);


    inputString = mySerial.readString();
    Serial.println(inputString);

     if(inputString.indexOf("0000000") > 0)
      {
             mySerial.println("ATH");
             delay(250);
            digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
            delay(250);
            digitalWrite( buzzer , HIGH); 
            delay(250);
            digitalWrite( LED , HIGH);
            delay(300);
            digitalWrite( relay , LOW);


            while(1){
               inputString = mySerial.readString();
                    Serial.println(inputString);
                  if (inputString.indexOf("00000000")>0 && inputString.indexOf("OFF") > -1){


                     digitalWrite( buzzer , LOW);
                     digitalWrite( LED , LOW);
                     goto m;
                  } 
            buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
           if (buttonState == HIGH) {
                    digitalWrite( buzzer , LOW);
                     digitalWrite( LED , LOW);
                   goto m ;
                   }
                   }

          }


    if(inputString.indexOf("000000") >0 && inputString.indexOf("1") > -1 )
      {

            digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
            delay(250);
            digitalWrite( buzzer , HIGH);
            delay(250);
            digitalWrite( LED , HIGH);
            delay(300);
            digitalWrite( relay , LOW);
               while(1){
                   inputString = mySerial.readString();
                    Serial.println(inputString);
                  if (inputString.indexOf("00000000")>0 && inputString.indexOf("OFF") > -1){


                     digitalWrite( buzzer , LOW);
                     digitalWrite( LED , LOW);
                     goto m;
                  } 

           buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
           if (buttonState == HIGH) {
                    digitalWrite( buzzer , LOW);
                      digitalWrite( LED , LOW);

                       goto m;
                   }

                   }

          }




  }
}
```